# Reducing amount of images shown out database PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, image

Lets start with;

```
 echo $query_row['winkels'];
```

This will echo;

```
<td style="margin-left:3px;"><img src="logo/15.png"/></td> <td style="margin-left:3px;"><img src="logo/11.png"/></td>
```

Out of my MySql Database, but on the page it will echo one image. If I put more in like example;

```
<td style="margin-left:3px;"><img src="logo/15.png"/></td> <td style="margin-left:3px;"><img src="logo/11.png"/></td> <td style="margin-left:3px;"><img src="logo/15.png"/></td> <td style="margin-left:3px;"><img src="logo/11.png"/></td>
```

It will echo 2 images.

When I have more than 20 images shown I want to reduce it to 5 images.

How can I do that?

For example;

```
$winkels_inject = $query_row['winkels'];
$sub_winkels = substr($winkels_inject, 0, 191);
echo $sub_winkels;
```

This is perfect when trying to reduce text, but that is what it does when I use it. It reduces the image links and removes html so the images will not be shown. So no image will be shown at all.

How to fix this?

Regards,
F4LLCON

Comment: You store the complete html code to display _all_ images in this single `winkels` column (in a single row)?

Comment: Store only the names of the images in the database, and build the rest in PHP.

Comment: That is true, because I have products, so I will display image logo of the stores who sell them, but every product has other store logo's. And i thought it might be easy to do. It was the easiest way to show images, but not to reduce images if I wanted because the code I've posted will reduce text, so the links will be reduced. You suggest another way to show images?

@Cito Could you give me one example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a design problem, the only thing you would need to store in a DB, is the number and then every number in a different row.

Anyway, a quick and very dirty solution:

```
$string_with_breaks = str_replace('td> <td', 'td>__break_here__<td', $query_row['winkels']);
$img_array = explode('__break_here__', $string_with_breaks);

// loop through array and only echo the first 5 elements
$count = 0;
foreach($img_array as $store)
{
  echo $store;
  $count++;
  if ($count > 4)
  {
     break;
  }
}
```

Miss (or add...) a space between the `td` tags and it will not work anymore...

Comment: @F4LLCON Because the result of `explode` is an array. You need to loop through the array to get to your strings, I'll update.

Comment: Now it shows the images again, but it does not limit it. Still showing all the images. Any suggestions?

Comment: @F4LLCON It should show a maximum of 5 entries from the array. What does `var_dump($img_array)` give you?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(342) "*here*" } *and between the quotes it displays 6 images.

Well this is also what is shows on another product:

" } Winkels:  array(1) { [0]=> string(342) " *with 6 images here*

Comment: @F4LLCON Well, then your string is not exactly like you said it was, see my comment at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for this! Sorry, my bad! I forgot to add space between them. It works now =D